# How can you change your python code after you deploy it to heroku using git , without downloading and reinstalling requirements everytime?

Tags: python, git, heroku

I recently used heroku for web scraping using selenium ( python ) .
I use these commands to deploy my python code to heroku :

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
heroku git:remote -a myappname
git push heroku master
```

But everytime I want to change my code a bit , It downloads and reinstalls chromedrive and many other things again .
Is there anyway to just push the changes of my python file to heroku ?

Sorry if my question is stupid . I'm new to git and heroku .

Comment: That's not possible on Heroku by design.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+%5Bpython%5D+reinstall+dependencies

Comment: The actual issue currently is https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/pull/948